# Windows, HDD, Accidentally clicked on format but cancelled now left with RAW disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, format

I have a Western Digital external HDD of 1 TB.

I accidentally used the following commands in `diskpart` onto my HDD:

1. select disk 2 (my HDD partition)
2. select partition '1'
3. clean
4. create partition primary
5. active
6. format fs=fat32 and then cancelled at 00% because I was supposed to apply these commands on to my pendrive and by mistake I did it on my HDD. Now I am left with a RAW drive but not yet formatted. Windows detecting it but tells me to format it.

Can I repair the drive to state in which it was before? the disk is still not formatted i.e I just initiated and canceled.

P.S. No physical damage in the drive also data is not overwritten.

Comment: You could try a utility like [`testdisk`](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) which could attempt to recover the partition table, though no absolute gaurentees of "untouched" recovery .. that is, you could rebuild the partition table to match your old one, and your old file table might still be intact, but if not, you might have to use a file recovery tool that can scan RAW drives and recover files from the format your drive was in (presumably NTFS) .. was it your main OS drive?

Comment: It was the "clean" command that nuked the partition tables.

Comment: also easeus partition recovery

Comment: @txtechhelp testdisk helped me but I made a quick search and it gave me a 20gb partition and I wrote that on the disk :(

Comment: @txtechhelp Deeper search was taking too much time like 6hrs = 1%

Comment: @Moab yea that clean destroyed everything for me. One 'CLEAN' command destroyed my hostel life pics, Counter Strike Videos :(

Comment: The deep search was looking for separate partitions because it couldn't find one that "made sense" .. the 20GB partition is probably just a garbage value it "thought" was a "good" partition based on the values written on disk .. 99% chance your partition and file table are hosed without serious knowledge of what you had on the disk before .. whatever you do next STOP writing to the disk and get a data recovery tool to read the drive in RAW format and see if you can recover your files this way .. it happens to the best of us, and then we get backups :)